# Play MP3 or WAV file via the Linux command line

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio

I would like to make an alarm system backed by a Ubuntu (no graphical interface) box, which plays various announcement and alarm audio tracks (.mp3 or .wav) via the command line.

For example:

```
$ root> audioplay ./hello.wav
```

The audio should come from the PC audio jack. I might also wrap it with another socket listener (for example, Ruby [Sinatra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinatra_(software))).

How can I do this?

Comment: Just in case you're looking for example files: `/usr/share/sounds` is a good place to look for them.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

mpg123 is a command-line utility which plays mp3 files. You can install it in Ubuntu with:

```
sudo apt-get install mpg123
```

Comment: This doesn't play wav files.

Answer (score 100):

The `play` command from the `sox` package will play any file format supported by `sox` using the default audio device, e.g

```
$ play something.mp3
$ play something.wav
```

You may need to install extra packages to gain support for all formats, for example on Ubuntu 11.04 the MP3 support is not available until you install `libsox-fmt-mp3`.

Comment: it also supports ogg files (and probably others).

Comment: In Ubuntu Xenial, there is `libsox-fmt-all` package to install all formats.

Comment: BTW, the `-v` option specify the volume, e.g `1` is normal, `0.5` is half, `2` is twice.

Answer (score 85):

The most standard way to play a WAV file in Linux is using the `aplay` command, which is part of the `ALSA` system.

```
aplay [flags] [filename [filename]] ...

aplay a.wav
```

Links: [(Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aplay) [(aplay man page)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/aplay)

(Both in Fedora and in Ubuntu/Mint it is part of the `alsa-utils` package)

This does not require any additional packages to your Linux installation like sox or mplayer or vlc, just the basic ALSA which is a part of any system nowadays.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  I added this alias to my shell config: alias beep="aplay --quiet /usr/share/sounds/pop.wav" .  That way I can get a notification when long running commands finish.  For example: compile && run && beep

Comment: Yes, Jesse! I do exactly the same with compiling (long file conversions, etc). 

I use sounds from here: ["Opilki sounds"](http://addons.miranda-im.org/details.php?action=viewfile&id=3379) (they are under the Creatve Commons license)  

forgive me this minor advertisement, i'm not related to the project in any way :)

Comment: Dead easy and already installed everywhere.

+1

Comment: Remember that you **can't** play an MP3 with `aplay`. You'll just get static.

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs, i wrote about WAV files only !

Comment: @Maxim I know! I just added that comment because I tried to play an mp3 :P

Comment: This is a correct answer. yeah you can install too many CLI multimedia players buy why not use a built-in one.

Answer (score 27):

Install `vlc` by using:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc vlc-plugin-pulse mozilla-plugin-vlc
```

Make sure that you have all repositories open. Also run the following before you install:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

VLC has a command-line operation method invoked by `cvlc`. The next part would be to write a `.sh` that will call the command. I am no good at writing bash scripts. The end-result would be something like:

```
cvlc xyz.mp3
cvlc --play-and-exit done.mp3
```

Comment: cvlc too slow to boot up? and need to run by a non-root user?

Comment: `cvlc --play-and-exit done.mp3` if you don't want to ctrl-c it.

Comment: `cvlc --play-and-exit --no-loop done.mp3` . I need the extra option `--no-loop`, so that the sound file is not repeated over and over. (vlc 2.2.2, xubuntu 16.04.4)

Comment: note that vlc usually depends on qt5 and X on some distribution, but mpg123 depends on only alsa-lib.

Answer (score 13):

On [Ubuntu 16.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29) (Xenial Xerus), there is no need to install anything. You can play a sound using `paplay [audio]` with is part of the PulseAudio sound server:

```
paplay mysound.mp3
```

Comment: I would think this works only if `paplay --list-file-formats` includes MP3 in the format list, which it does not on my machine (which, admittedly, is not Ubuntu). Does paplay ever really include MP3?

Comment: Correct. WAV seems to be on that list but not MP3. You might need to install proprietary codecs. On Ubuntu that would be `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`.

Comment: This actually worked for mp3 files and it was on my system all along :o

Answer (score 12):

You can simply pipe your sound data to the pc speaker device:

```
cat rawsound | /dev/pcsp
```

Comment: I very much doubt that is going to work with MP3 files.

Comment: It won't work with mp3 encoded sound of course, but it will work with raw wav data

Comment: I don't have the /dev/pcsp device. What else can I try?

Comment: I get "cat: rawsound: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden"

Comment: This is so beautifully simple. I love it.

Answer (score 8):

[MPlayer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPlayer) is another player which can play pretty much any audio/video format from command line. To install it in Ubuntu just execute this command:

```
sudo apt-get install mplayer
```

You can then play the file using this syntax:

```
mplayer [path to file]
```

Answer (score 7):

I found another way:

[FFmpeg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFmpeg) is installed on my [Ubuntu 19.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_19.04_(Disco_Dingo)) (Disco Dingo)

So:

```
$ ffplay music.mp3

-nodisp
hide spectrum analyzer

-nostats
hide cursor/file information

-hide_banner
hide build information


Hide all (no output):

$ ffplay music.mp3 -nodisp -nostats -hide_banner
```

Comment: Is there a way to use the interactive commands with stdin and `-nodisp`?

Answer (score 1):

### canberra-gtk-play

For simple Bash scripts [MPlayer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPlayer) is probably a bit too heavy and too verbose in terms of output. A built-in option is `canberra-gtk-play` which comes preinstalled on Ubuntu:

```
canberra-gtk-play --file=/usr/share/sounds/gnome/default/alerts/drip.ogg
```

Note: it uses the alerts volume, and you must pass `--file=` in order to play a file from a path.

It can also play a sound by id which represents the file name without extension of media files under `/usr/share/sounds` (apparently this only works for sounds that are registered as part of a sound theme):

```
canberra-gtk-play --id="desktop-login"

canberra-gtk-play --id="message"
```

### gst-launch-1.0/gst-launch-0.10

Another option is using the [gstreamer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/faq/html/chapter-using.html) command-line tools which are present on most modern Linux boxes:

```
gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=file:///usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/message.ogg
```

To suppress all output redirect it to `/dev/null`:

```
gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=file:///usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/message.ogg > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Both `gst-launch-1.0` and `gst-launch-0.10` might be present on your system.

Answer (score 0):

You can play all sound files (mp3, wav, ogg etc) via ffplay

```
ffplay -nodisp -autoexit ticktock.mp3
```

ffmpeg is very powerful and you can steam it to other sockets as well as sound cards.