# OSX bash command line countdown timer

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, bash

I found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/611538/is-there-a-way-to-display-a-countdown-or-stopwatch-timer-in-a-terminal) on superuser the following nice countdown script that I could include in my .bash_profile:

```
function countdown(){  
   date1=$((`date +%s` + $1));   
   while [ "$date1" -ne `date +%s` ]; do   
     echo -ne "$(date -u --date @$(($date1 - `date +%s`)) +%H:%M:%S)\r";  
     sleep 0.1  
  done  
}
```

It doesn't work on OSX, i understand, because of the differences in the `date` command. Another user commented as such but the problem remained unresolved in that question.

The same problem (I think) is also discussed and solved [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115736/unable-to-use-date-command-to-change-specific-date-format-in-bash-shell-on-os-x) but I cannot work out how to modify the countdown script to utilise this solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally, I'd refactor that a bit for readability (still relying on GNU date)

```
function countdown(){  
    local now=$(date +%s)
    local end=$((now + $1))
    while (( now < end )); do   
        printf "%s\r" "$(date -u -d @$((end - now)) +%T)"  
        sleep 0.25  
        now=$(date +%s)
    done  
    echo
}
```

Mapping the date calls to OSX's BSD date ([man page here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/date.1.html))

It looks like the GNU date invocation

```
date -u -d @$((end - now)) +%T
```

translates to this BSD date invocation

```
date -u -j -f %s $((end - now)) +%T
```

but that's untested.

Comment: Bash is returning an unexpected EOF error on the printf line.

Comment: Are you sure you have all the quotes matching. The code I posted works (with bash version 4 at any rate)

Comment: my fault: one of my double quotes was curly (damn autocorrect....)  The code works perfectly now.

Comment: Time to pick a better editor.

Comment: You could add `if (( $# <1 )); then return; fi` as the first line for a bit of robustness.

Comment: so, i need some like: call countdonw() ? to use this?

Comment: No, just `countdown 15` or any other number of seconds. You inkove shell functions like any other command: command and arguments separated with whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

I tried @glenn's answer on macOS Mojave in Bash and Zsh, and it worked well.  The last `echo` in his code near the last line might not be needed:

```
function countdown() {  
    local now=$(date +%s)
    local end=$((now + $1))
    while (( now < end )); do   
        printf "%s\r" "$(date -u -j -f %s $((end - now)) +%T)"  
        sleep 0.25  
        now=$(date +%s)
    done  
}
```

and to count down:

```
countdown 30                       # for 30 seconds
countdown $((10*60))               # 10 minutes
countdown $((1*60*60 + 30*60))     # 1 hour 30 minutes
```

I am not so familiar with shell scripts, so perhaps somebody could add a display for number of days if the countdown is more than a day.

To give an audio bell at the end of the countdown, add an extra line near the end:

```
function countdown() {  
    local now=$(date +%s)
    local end=$((now + $1))
    while (( now < end )); do   
        printf "%s\r" "$(date -u -j -f %s $((end - now)) +%T)"  
        sleep 0.25  
        now=$(date +%s)
    done  
    echo -en "\a"
}
```